# Kivy row data on click with MDDataTable

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I have an MDDataTable that has a bind(on_row_press) where I'm trying to return one specific column of that row, regardless of where it is clicked. I couldn't find anything in the documentation. Is this possible?

Simple example:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable
from kivy.metrics import dp

class TestApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        mddatatable = MDDataTable(
            pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5},
            size_hint=(1, 1),
            check=False,
            use_pagination=True,
            rows_num=10,
            column_data=[
                ("ID", dp(5)),
                ("Description", dp(30)),
                ("Value", dp(10))
            ],
            row_data=[
                ("1", "Description One Here", "$100"),
                ("2", "Description Two Here", "$200"),
                ("3", "Description Three Here", "$300")
            ]
        )
        mddatatable.bind(on_row_press=self.print_id)
        return mddatatable

    def print_id(self, instance_table, instance_row):
        print(instance_row.text)

TestApp().run()
```

Right now, if you click on "Description One Here" it will output "Description One Here". Similarly if you click on "$100" it will output "$100". I'm looking to output the ID column, so even if you click somewhere else in row 1, it'll still output "1".

Answer (score 0):

Use KivyMD library from master branch, not from PyPi.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the method <recycle_data> of the MDDataTable, KivyMD has its proper way to index the items of raw, for example: table[0][0] does not mean the first item of the first row, so when you click on a row you should get the start and end indexes assined by KivyMD for this row, here an example to loop over a row items:

```
def on_row_press(self,  table, row):
    # get start index from selected row item range
    start_index, end_index = row.table.recycle_data[row.index]["range"]
    print(start_index)
    print(end_index)
    # loop over selected row items
    for i in range(start_index, end_index):
        print(row.table.recycle_data[i]["text"])
```

for your case, supposing that the 'ID column' is the second column, its corresponding value:

```
row.table.recycle_data[start_index + 1]["text"]
```